# BSurface Addon Option Disappeared from Project

Tags: add-on, retopology

I was working on retopologizing this yesterday using the Bsurfaces Addon with no issues. I open the same file today and the Bsurface button under tools is completely gone and when I try to click "Continue Retopo" it gives me this error and I completely don't have any idea what it means.
I didn't move the file or anything after saving it. And when I open a new blender project I can use the Bsurface addon just fine, it has the bsurface button. I tried to append this mesh and retopo mesh into a new file but it gives the same error. I will break into little tiny pieces if I have to start all over on this because I'm horrible at retopology and just this little bit I've done took me like 4 hours. Can I fix this?

[image: Problem Error Message]

Comment: Is this the BSurfaces add-on that is included to Blender? I just wonder because in the error message there is Speedretopo mentioned. Is this another add-on you installed recently?

Comment: Yes, this is an extra addon. It's probably speedretopo, for some reason I just thought it was called b-surface addon. I installed it a while ago and hadn't touched it for months. I used it just fine on another project over multiple days before, so I'm just confused why it's not working for this.